# Error al dar formato fecha dd/MM/YYYY

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Al mostrar una fecha de tipo **Date** con el formato **dd/MM/YYYY**

```
Date fecha= new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
System.out.println(formatoFecha.format(fecha));
```

La salida que deseo obtener es: 29/12/2022
La salida que obtengo es: 29/12/2023

Pero si muestro la fecha sin formato

```
Date fecha= new Date();
System.out.println(fecha);
```

La salida que obtengo es: **Thu Dec 29 08:45:59 COT 2022**

Observación:
Este error si puedo llamarlo así me da desde el 23/12/2022, anteriormente a esa fecha si me funcionaba correctamente el formato: **SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY")**

Comment: Prueba con `("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev efectivamente se corrigío, pero ya tenia más de un año con el formato ``dd/MM/YYYY`` y no hubo problemas, sabes a que se debe esto?

Comment: Aquí hay un enlace donde se explica a más detalle https://dev.to/shane/yyyy-vs-yyyy-the-day-the-java-date-formatter-hurt-my-brain-4527